# How can fix cpu doesn't support required features (vt-x or svm) for AMD CPU

Tags: android, android-studio

I can't run program of android studio. 

because this alert dialog "**your cpu doesn't support required features (vt-x or svm)**".

I use CPU AMD A8-4500M.
I try setup another program, but it not work

How can I fix it.
Thanks you so much.

[image]

Comment: use for example Genymotion

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable your cpu's virtualization technology if you have. you can check it from your task manager>performance option or from your cpu boot option. if you have virtualization supported cpu you should enable it. if after enabling virtualization the problem remains you should install a fresh android studio. and if you don't have virtualization option then you have to download an arm system image for your emulator or you can try genymotion emulator. hope it will work for you.